# Render to texture - texture formats and parameters?

Tags: opengl

When I render to a texture (stored in a bound framebuffer object), do any of the following texture parameters matter?

```
GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S
GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T
GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER
GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER
```

It's also redundant to generate mipmaps, right? (Might be a stupid question, but I'm just making sure!)

What about data types (the `type` parameter)?
Does `type` have to be `GL_FLOAT`? If not, what's the difference between specifying `type` as `GL_FLOAT` and `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`?

Also, every doc I find on the web regarding Texture2D info (e.g. https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) is missing some info. (namely the `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16/24/32`, and `GL_RGB16` flags. other sources miss a lot more).

Is there a source for complete info on these stuff? (preferably specialized for the render-to-texture technique)

Comment: I don't think these parameters have any effect when rendering to texture. Yes, mipmaps are redundant when rendering to texture. `Type` is how color components are stored. Nope, `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` is also valid. The difference between them is obivous, isn't it? `..._FLOAT`  stores your colors as four floats, `..._BYTE` stores them as 4 bytes. And if you want a complete doc, just download last compatibility profile spec.

Comment: I was asking about the types because in [this](http://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-Lighting/Deferred-Shading) tutorial the author sets most textures as `GL_FLOAT`, but for some unknown reason he sets the last texture as `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`. Any idea why?

Comment: `..._FLOAT` offers better precision, but it's often redundant, you will not see any difference between it and `..._BYTE` on most monitors. But if result is used in computations, float can be better. Maybe it is the reason.

Comment: "*It's also redundant to generate mipmaps, right?*" What do you mean by "redundant"?

Comment: Unneeded.Useless. A waste of time

Comment: @Pilpel: First, that's not what "[redundant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/redundant?db=*)" means. If something is "redundant", then it is something that has already been done, and therefore does not need to be done again. If you render to a texture, generating mipmaps would only be "redundant" if rendering to that texture was how you generated mipmaps for it. Secondly, if you need mipmaps for your render target, why would generating them be "Unneeded.Useless. A waste of time"? And if you don't need mipmaps for them, why would you even ask if you should generate them?

Comment: Ha, my dictionary failed me then :P. Thanks for clearing that up. My question was more like asking if there was some mysterious, nontrivial meaning to generating mipmaps for a texture that gets rendered to.

Comment: Also note that according to [this](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/198121-Render-to-texture-texture-formats-and-parameters?p=1281264&posted=1#post1281264) post, if `type` and `format` don't matter if `data` is null!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I render to a texture (stored in a bound framebuffer object), do any of the following texture parameters matter?

No. While those parameters can be set in a way that breaks [Texture Completeness](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Completeness), they do not affect [Framebuffer Object Completeness](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Completeness). No [texture](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Parameter) or [sampling](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampling_Parameter) parameters can affect framebuffer completeness.

> What about data types (the type parameter)? Does type have to be GL_FLOAT? If not, what's the difference between specifying type as GL_FLOAT and GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE?

Even if you are transferring no bytes of data (ie: passing `nullptr`), you *must* provide [pixel transfer parameters](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer) that are *legal values*. If you don't, then your call to `glTexImage2D` will fail with an error.

For example, from the OpenGL Specification version 4.5:

> An `INVALID_OPERATION` error is generated if one of the base internal
>   format and `format` is `DEPTH_COMPONENT` or `DEPTH_STENCIL`, and the other
>   is neither of these values.

So your internal format and pixel transfer format must at least be able to talk to one another, even if they're never actually used. So if you're making a depth/stencil texture, you must use `GL_DEPTH_STENCIL` as the pixel transfer format.

Or you can just stop screwing around with bad APIs and use [`glTexStorage`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Storage#Immutable_storage).

Comment: `glTexStorage` is core since version 4.2 though. Are you sure about the "must be able to talk" part? The [opengl.org guys](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/198121-Render-to-texture-texture-formats-and-parameters?p=1281266&posted=1#post1281266) suggest "Just setting them to something like GL_RED and GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE will do."

Comment: @Pilpel: I cannot be responsible for the advise others give. I have now updated the post, providing you a *direct quote* from the OpenGL specification. You can choose to believe that or not.